# How to pass an extra parameter to function in map Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

If I have something like this:

dataArray.map(self.aggregationFunction);

but I want to pass the aggregationFunction another parameter, is this possible in Javascript? I tried adding .bind(extra parameter) but it didn't seem to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than passing the function directly, you could pass in a function which calls the function with the additional parameter, e.g:

```
let someOtherValue = 123;
dataArray.map((dataItem) => aggregationFunction(dataItem, someOtherValue))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had seen this earlier. Worked like a charm!